# Unable to connect to VNC server over internet

Tags: cisco, nat, vnc

I have a server that I need `VNC` access to over the internet and I am having an issue. I referenced [this](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/docs/get-connected.html) site as the way to do it and went to establishing a direct connection over the internet. Here is what I did:
I have a block of 5 public ip addresses from my `ISP` and one of them I'm using to statically `NAT` from this internal server (`192.168.2.6`). The `RealVNC` server is enabled on that internal server and I have connected to it over the `LAN`. I have confirmed that port `5900` is open on my public IP address with [this](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) website, but when I try to use `VNC Viewer` to connect to my public IP address, I get an error message saying "too many security failures."
I don't see which step I missed, what am I doing wrong that I can't access my VNC server?

Comment: Exactly how did you "statically `NAT`" your address?

Comment: @MichaelHampton ip nat inside source 192.168.2.6 my.public.ip.address

Comment: Should the command be **ip nat inside source static...?**

Comment: @joeqwerty yeah, sorry, editing right now

Comment: The "too many security failures" error implies you have made a connection successfully (so nothing is wrong with your NAT) but the VNC Server app has blacklisted the connection because of too many incorrect password attempts. Check the server logging to see if you are getting connection attempts from addresses other than the one you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, when you need to manage a server behind a gateway that is connected to the Internet using NAT, I would suggest "easy to use" Real VNC or TeamViewer.
Are freemium and if you don't need special requirements, those tools let you do the job done in few minutes.
Hope it can help

Comment: That's what I'm using right now is RealVNC